# TSQL - Problem converting and updating a float column

Tags: t-sql

I have tried many ways but could not find the answer. My problem is:

there is Table `ORG_DATA_AS_VARCHAR` with a column`FLOATNMBRS (varchar)`

```
FLOATNMBRS 
--------------------------
0
0
*0,25 /*Yeah, there is a star in data ... bad data quality ....*/
*0,31
0
```

Now, my aim is to convert this strings to a `float` and update these new float values to a new (existing) table `CONVERTED_DATA`:

```
FLOATNMBRS (float)
--------------------------
0
0
0.25 
0.31
0
...
```

What I have tried:

```
UPDATE CONVERTED_DATA
SET
    FLOATNMBRS  = b.newValue
FROM 
    (
    Select convert (float, replace(replace(FLOATNMBRS, '*', ''),',','.')) as newValue from 
    ORG_DATA_AS_VARCHAR
    ) b
```

or

Replacing and converting it and create a `#Temp` Table with the new Values and Update `CONVERTED_DATA` with values from `#Temp`.

but everytime I ended up like:

```
FLOATNMBRS (float)
--------------------------
0
0
0
0
0
```

All values were updated as `0`.

When I tried:

```
Select convert (float, replace(replace(FLOATNMBRS, '*', ''),',','.')) as newValue from 
    ORG_DATA_AS_VARCHAR
```

the result is correct. Even when I copy the value to `#Temp`. All values are correct.

Does someone know what I m doing wrong ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are possibly not matching the records in the 2 tables. It is not clear from your example how the rows are identified (what's the key).

Assuming you have the same `ID` in ORG_DATA_AS_VARCHAR and CONVERTED_DATA tables, this works:

```sql
create table #ORG_DATA_AS_VARCHAR (ID int, floatnmbrs_varchar varchar(128))
create table #CONVERTED_DATA (ID int, floatnmbrs float)
go


insert into #ORG_DATA_AS_VARCHAR   (ID, floatnmbrs_varchar)
values (1, '0'), (2, '0'), (3, '*0,25'), (4, '*0.31'), (5, '0')

insert into #CONVERTED_DATA   (ID, floatnmbrs)
values (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0)
go


update #CONVERTED_DATA
set floatnmbrs  = x.converted
from (
    select ID, converted = convert(float, replace(replace(floatnmbrs_varchar, '*', ''), ',', '.'))
    from #ORG_DATA_AS_VARCHAR  
) as x
where x.ID = #CONVERTED_DATA.ID

select * from #CONVERTED_DATA


go

drop table #ORG_DATA_AS_VARCHAR  
drop table #CONVERTED_DATA  
go
```